# Comparison Theorem for Integral Calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, integration, infinity

[image: Question]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/36b9ba93c81d90d725ca2036deb1fc7d.png?1358303690))</sub>

I have narrowed it down to C, E, and F, since we know that $1/x^{1/5}$ is always greater than the original function for all $x\geq 1$. However, the second set of conditions is more difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what it means, sorry...How can I change it?

Comment: go to your answered questions and *choose* the answer that you liked better. You can upvote many answers in each question you ask, but you can "accept" only one.

Comment: Looks nicer now, right?

Comment: Indeed it does. Way to go, most people appreciates that kind of things here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \ge 1$, then $(x + e^{2x})^{\frac{1}{5}} \ge (e^{2x})^{\frac{1}{5}} = e^{\frac{2x}{5}}$.  So $(x+e^{2x})^{-\frac{1}{5}}\le e^{-\frac{2x}{5}}$.

$\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} e^{-\frac{2x}{5}} dx = \frac{5}{2}e^{-\frac{2}{5}} < \infty$.  So it's f).